# Accidentally Deleted the Android Support Library in the SDK Manager

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I accidentally deleted the Android Support Library Folder in the SDK Mngr so i can re-install it again, to enable the action bar. Unfortunately what I did brought up alot of errors in my current project even after trying to re-install the Android Support Library it's still the same situation. Here is the Problem log/list output..

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Activity cannot be resolved to a type   SplashScreenActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 4  Java Problem
Handler cannot be resolved to a type    SplashScreenActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 12 Java Problem
Intent cannot be resolved to a type SplashScreenActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 16 Java Problem
Bundle cannot be resolved to a type SplashScreenActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 8  Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SplashScreenActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 10 Java Problem
Intent cannot be resolved to a type SplashScreenActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 16 Java Problem
The method finish() is undefined for the type SplashScreenActivity  SplashScreenActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 20 Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type RestaurantPickUpActivity RestaurantPickUpActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  RestaurantPickUpActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
Activity cannot be resolved to a type   RestaurantPickUpActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 6  Java Problem
Bundle cannot be resolved to a type RestaurantPickUpActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 9  Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  RestaurantPickUpActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 11 Java Problem
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type RestaurantPickUpActivity must override or implement a supertype method RestaurantPickUpActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 15 Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type HitchARideActivity   HitchARideActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type HitchARideActivity must override or implement a supertype method   HitchARideActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 15 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HitchARideActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
Activity cannot be resolved to a type   HitchARideActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 6  Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HitchARideActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 11 Java Problem
Bundle cannot be resolved to a type HitchARideActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 9  Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  ForgotPassActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 31 Java Problem
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type ForgotPassActivity must override or implement a supertype method   ForgotPassActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 29 Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type ForgotPassActivity   ForgotPassActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 31 Java Problem
The method setImageResource(int) is undefined for the type ImageView    HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 114    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  ForgotPassActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 16 Java Problem
View.OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type   ForgotPassActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
Bundle cannot be resolved to a type ForgotPassActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 12 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  ForgotPassActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 14 Java Problem
Activity cannot be resolved to a type   ForgotPassActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 9  Java Problem
Intent cannot be resolved to a type HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 72 Java Problem
Intent cannot be resolved to a type HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 75 Java Problem
Intent cannot be resolved to a type HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 66 Java Problem
Intent cannot be resolved to a type HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 69 Java Problem
AdapterView cannot be resolved to a type    HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 59 Java Problem
Intent cannot be resolved to a type HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 63 Java Problem
The method setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){}) is undefined for the type ListView   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 56 Java Problem
AdapterView cannot be resolved to a type    HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 56 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 44 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 55 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 38 Java Problem
ArrayAdapter cannot be resolved to a type   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 43 Java Problem
List cannot be resolved to a type   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 38 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 38 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 37 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 37 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 113    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 110    Java Problem
TextView cannot be resolved to a type   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 110    Java Problem
TextView cannot be resolved to a type   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 110    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 106    Java Problem
TextView cannot be resolved to a type   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 106    Java Problem
TextView cannot be resolved to a type   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 106    Java Problem
The method setImageResource(int) is undefined for the type ImageView    HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 103    Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 102    Java Problem
List cannot be resolved to a type   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 99 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 96 Java Problem
The method getLayoutInflater() is undefined for the type HomeActivity.MyListAdapter HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 96 Java Problem
ViewGroup cannot be resolved to a type  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 92 Java Problem
List cannot be resolved to a type   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 86 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 86 Java Problem
ArrayAdapter cannot be resolved to a type   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 83 Java Problem
Bundle cannot be resolved to a type LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 12 Java Problem
Activity cannot be resolved to a type   LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 9  Java Problem
TextView cannot be resolved to a type   LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 16 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 14 Java Problem
Activity cannot be resolved to a type   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 11 Java Problem
List cannot be resolved to a type   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 12 Java Problem
Bundle cannot be resolved to a type HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 15 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type HomeActivity must override or implement a supertype method HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 27 Java Problem
View.OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type   LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 39 Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type HomeActivity HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 29 Java Problem
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type LogInActivity must override or implement a supertype method    LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 52 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 29 Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type LogInActivity    LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 54 Java Problem
List cannot be resolved to a type   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 34 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 34 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 54 Java Problem
View.OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type   LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 27 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 34 Java Problem
List cannot be resolved to a type   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 35 Java Problem
TextView cannot be resolved to a type   LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 38 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 35 Java Problem
TextView cannot be resolved to a type   LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 38 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 35 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 38 Java Problem
List cannot be resolved to a type   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 36 Java Problem
TextView cannot be resolved to a type   LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 16 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 36 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 16 Java Problem
View.OnClickListener cannot be resolved to a type   LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 36 Java Problem
List cannot be resolved to a type   HomeActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 37 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  LogInActivity.java  /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 26 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  EventPickUpActivity.java    /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type EventPickUpActivity  EventPickUpActivity.java    /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
Bundle cannot be resolved to a type EventPickUpActivity.java    /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 9  Java Problem
Activity cannot be resolved to a type   EventPickUpActivity.java    /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 6  Java Problem
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type EventPickUpActivity must override or implement a supertype method  EventPickUpActivity.java    /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 15 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  EventPickUpActivity.java    /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 11 Java Problem
Bundle cannot be resolved to a type SignUpActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 10 Java Problem
Activity cannot be resolved to a type   SignUpActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 7  Java Problem
Unable to resolve target 'android-17' until the SDK is loaded.  PickMe      Unknown Android Target Problem
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type SignUpActivity must override or implement a supertype method   SignUpActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SignUpActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 12 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  SignUpActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 19 Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type SignUpActivity   SignUpActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 19 Java Problem
Activity cannot be resolved to a type   CarHireActivity.java    /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 6  Java Problem
Bundle cannot be resolved to a type PickMeActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 9  Java Problem
Activity cannot be resolved to a type   PickMeActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 6  Java Problem
Bundle cannot be resolved to a type CarHireActivity.java    /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 9  Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  CarHireActivity.java    /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 11 Java Problem
Activity cannot be resolved to a type   CodeVerificationActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 6  Java Problem
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type CarHireActivity must override or implement a supertype method  CarHireActivity.java    /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 15 Java Problem
Bundle cannot be resolved to a type CodeVerificationActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 9  Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  PickMeActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type CarHireActivity  CarHireActivity.java    /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type PickMeActivity   PickMeActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  CarHireActivity.java    /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type PickMeActivity must override or implement a supertype method   PickMeActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 15 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  PickMeActivity.java /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 11 Java Problem
The method onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu) of type CodeVerificationActivity must override or implement a supertype method CodeVerificationActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 15 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  CodeVerificationActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 11 Java Problem
R cannot be resolved to a variable  CodeVerificationActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
The method getMenuInflater() is undefined for the type CodeVerificationActivity CodeVerificationActivity.java   /PickMe/src/com/nanoxcorp/pickme    line 17 Java Problem
```

Comment: have you tried to import that library again to the project..??

Comment: or right click -> android tools -> add support library -> install?

Comment: try in eclipse opening the sdk manager, and putting a checkmark on the support library, its one of the top packages